# side navigational unmoveable buttons

Tags: html, button, static, navigation

Can anybody tell me how can I embed a side button on my website like the one in this [site](http://jobs.freelanceswitch.com/jobs/19706).

Also I've seen some sites with unmovable chat box. Could anybody please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the `position:fixed` attribute in CSS.

It is locked in place on the screen, and does not move when the page scrolls.

To embed, just use a `<div style="display:block; z-index:999; position:fixed; top:0px; height:100px;">Content</div>`, and your content will be 100px down on the left of the screen.

`z-index` and `display` are attributes for specifying layers and wrapping respectively.